# Using if statement to raname a variable in a list of dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Good morning!
I need a little help with a problem that I can't solve on my own, I have dataframe list called df_2 that looks like this:

```
PP     VAR
user1   x

PP     VAR
user2   y
```

The person using my app is the one important to me but I cannot know who between user 1 or 2 they are, so I'm using radio button to ask them directly:

```
self.user = tk.StringVar(self)
self.user.set('0')
self.user1 = tk.Radiobutton(self.step2_frame, text=df_2[0].loc[0,:]['PP'], value="im_user1", var=self.user,  cursor="hand2")
self.user2 = tk.Radiobutton(self.step2_frame, text=df_2[1].loc[1,:]['PP'], value="im_user2", var=self.user,  cursor="hand2")
```

after that I want to have a list of dataframe that look like this if for example a person say they are the second user:

```
PP            VAR SAVE
notimportant   x  user1=notimp


PP         VAR SAVE
important   y  user2=imp
```

I'm stuck at this function since it doesn't change the PP value in what I want

```
def rename(self):
    if self.user.get() == "im_user1":
       dfs_2[0]['PP'].replace(dfs_2[0].loc[0,:]['PP'],'important', regex=True)
       dfs_2[1]['PP'].replace(dfs_2[1].loc[1,:]['PP'],'notimportant', regex=True)            

     if self.user.get() == "im_user2":
        dfs_2[0]['PP'].replace(dfs_2[0].loc[0,:]['PP'],'notimportant', regex=True)
        dfs_2[1]['PP'].replace(dfs_2[1].loc[1,:]['PP'],'important', regex=True)
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is just *"how to replace the value in a dataframe cell"*, you should use the `at` or `iat` functions:

```
dfs_2.at[0, 'PP'] = 'important'
```

Comment: That was my first thought too. But from what I understand `dfs_2` is a list of dataframes. With that in mind the original notation makes perfect sense.

Comment: Ok, so can you just iterate over the list? Like `for x in dfs_2: x.at[0, 'PP'] = 'important'` for example ?

Comment: That would probably work (if my assumption is correct). But I don't think there's the need to access individual cells, because the operation in question (`.replace(...)`) can be done for the whole column at once.